# .htaccess alow few .htm and .html files only

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with content below which is changing my **index.php?page=aboutus** to **aboutus.htm**
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(.html)/?$ index.php?page=$1

I am using $_GET["page"] to print content from database using PHP, but if someone type **test.html** it is checking database for **test** data,

How can I use .htaccess to alow only few .html files in url such as aboutus.html, home.html, projects.html etc...

Thanks

Comment: why not restrict the database access directly in your php script ? use an array to specify what pages you allow the user to view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I want to have 404 erroDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(aboutus|home|projects)\.html/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

PS. why do you want to keep the '.html' part in your urls? They don't really add anything.

Answer (score 0):

as I said in my comment, you could do the verification directly in your php script.

anyway if you really want to do that with an `.htaccess` file you might consider using RewriteMap :

[Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html).

however it can be a bit complex if you're not familiar with it and if the verification apply on a small set of files should be better to use the `RewriteCond` directive :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(aboutus|home|projects)
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)(.*)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @noorahmad you're welcome, I edited the code, cause there were some issue with it (the starting slash and the possible path after the first segment in your uri). I hope that will help.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but still I have some problems.
Edit:
This line of code helped me a lot: 
RewriteRule ^(aboutus|home|projects)\.html/?$ index.php?page=$1
in case anyone face with the same problem